# Constructor and method

Tags: java

For my project I have a question that says newGenerationNumber an integer. If the argument passed as the parameter is less than zero, set the generationNumber instance variable to zero. Otherwise assign newGenerationNumber to the generationNumber instance variable. I'm confused on how to start this.  My code I out is 
Private int generationNumber

Then I made a if

```
If (generationNumber >0)  
 generationNumber = generationNumber
```

I'm confused if this is right and if I need to make a else

Comment: The assignment `generationNumber = generationNumber;` has no effect since you only re-assign the current value. But I do not understand what tue question has to do with constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
generationNumber = newGenerationNumber;
if (generationNumber < 0) {
    generationNumber = 0;
}
```

else it stays the way it is

Comment: It's actually written very similar here is the age part where I used public Guppy newAgeInWeeks an integer. If the argument passed as the parameter is less than zero or greater than fifty, set the ageInWeekageInWeek instance variable to zero. Otherwise assign newAgeInWeeks to the ageInWeeks instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

An `if...else` is a good choice here, but not the only one.

```
int generationNumber;

public Guppy (int newGenerationNumber) {
    if (newGenerationNumber > 0) {
        generationNumber = newGenerationNumber;
    } else {
        generationNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Instance int primitives have the value of `0` by default. This means that you could leave the `else` part and only check if it's positive.

Comment: But how do I start it? I can't do a constructor public Guppy () { it's giving me error

Comment: Also what does the part whereally it's asking about newGenerationNumber mean?

Comment: @user6394146 Here it is. `newGenerationNumber` is the name of your parameter from the constructor.

Comment: Wen I put public guppy (int newgenerationnumber) it gives me constructor guppy is already defined in a class

Comment: Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

It says if the **new**GenerationInstance parameter (argument) is less than 0.

So I'd probably use the conditional operator (`x ? y : z`):

```
public Guppy(int newGenerationInstance) {
    this.generationInstance = newGenerationInstance < 0 ? 0 : newGenerationInstance;
}
```

or alternately you can use `if`/`else` if you prefer:

```
public Guppy(int newGenerationInstance) {
    if (newGenerationInstance < 0) {
        this.generationInstance = 0;
    } else {
        this.generationInstance = newGenerationInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys I tried public Guppy (int generationNumber)but it's giving me error because I made a public Guppy (int ageInWeeks)

Comment: @user6394146: You can only have one `Guppy(int)` constructor. Presumably the assignment tells you to do something else with the age aspect.

Answer (score 0):

for the simple solution, i would write the code like below

```
public class NewNumberGenerationClass {
//instance variable because you can access this with the instance of the class
private int NewGenerationNumber;
public NewNumberGenerationClass(int i){
    setNewGenerationNumber(i);
}
//setting value before getting it
public void setNewGenerationNumber(int i)
{
    if(i < 0)
    {
        this.NewGenerationNumber = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this.NewGenerationNumber = i;
    }
}
//access vaule using get method
public int getNewGenerationNumber()
{
    return this.NewGenerationNumber;
}
   public static void main(String[] args){
       NewNumberGenerationClass s = new NewNumberGenerationClass(-5);
       NewNumberGenerationClass s1 = new NewNumberGenerationClass(5);

       System.out.println(s.getNewGenerationNumber());
       System.out.println(s1.getNewGenerationNumber());
   }
```

}